# What does Yoneda's Lemma tell us about a representable functor?

Tags: category-theory, functors, yoneda-lemma

Someone told me that a functor being representable is good because we can use Yoneda's Lemma. But I'm not sure how Yoneda's Lemma tells us anything new given that a functor is representable. For example, say I have a representable functor $F$ from a category $C$ to $Sets$ with representation $(A, \phi).$ This tells me that $Nat(h^A, F) \cong F(A).$ I guess this tells me that $\phi \in Nat(h^A, F)$ can be associated with some $u \in F(A)$ but what else?

Comment: Yoneda's lemma is often useful because it tells us that we can think of our category as a category of functors. If our functor is representable that means we can think of it as an object in the category

Comment: Sometimes you want to compute the set of natural transformations from a functor to another functor. The Yoneda lemma makes this very easy to do if the first functor is representable! There are lots of applications of this; see, for example, https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/operations-and-lawvere-theories/ and https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/operations-pro-objects-and-grothendiecks-galois-theory/.